# bitcoind localhost port 18332: Connection refused Ubuntu 18

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, testnet

Trying to connect to testnet using curl from localhost on ubuntu server. Tried lots of combinations of bitcoin.conf and ports.

Here's my config:

```
server=1
daemon=1
testnet=1
rpcuser=user
rpcpassword=pswd
test.rpcport=18332
rpcconnect=127.0.0.1
rpcbind=127.0.0.1:18332
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `test.rpcport=18332` that's not right.

Comment: Thanks, I've solved the issue, it was a silly mistake on my side

Comment: Please either delete the question or post an answer explaining how you solved your problem, thanks.